# jQuery on() event only working with $(document)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's `.on()` event handler and it's only working when I use `$(document)`.

This works:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on("click", ".search .remove", function(e) {
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

This does not work:

```
$(function() {
    $(".search .remove").on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```

Nothing happens on that second one...no errors or anything. It just doesn't fire.

Comment: are .search and .remove inserted dynamically after dom ready event (maybe via ajax)?

Comment: Do a `console.log($(".search .remove").length)` to make sure the selector is fine.

Comment: write console.log($(".search .remove")) and find out wheather element is found or not

Comment: I'm cloning an element and `.search .remove` is part of that...so yes, they are inserted dynamically.

Comment: So it's fine (and recommended) using event delegation as in your first example, unless you clone even the handlers associated along with your elements

Comment: @Shpigford `$(".search .remove").on("click", function(e) {` won't work if the element doesn't exist at the time the code is run. Your first method is correct way for dynamic elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using two different syntaxes of .on which have two very different outcomes.

Your first is:

```
$(context).on("event","targetselector",handler)
```

This binds the event to context, and any events of type `event` that gets to the `context` that has an `e.target` that can be selected with `targetselector` will trigger the handler with `e.target` as the context. this is commonly known as event delegation.

Your second syntax is

```
$(targetselector).on("event",handler)
```

In this case, the event is bound directly to the elements currently on the page that match `targetselector`, not future elements. This is essentially the same as the old `.bind`.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example doesn't work because your elements are created dynamically. When using `.on()` with dynamically inserted elements, you have to bind it via an element that isn't inserted dynamically, i.e. one that exists on the page at load time.

You can continue to use `document` as an ancestor element but in terms of performance you might want to find an element closer in the DOM to `".search .remove"`.

From the jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on `.on()`:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>   Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This
>   element could be the container element of a view in a
>   Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event
>   handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The
>   document element is available in the head of the document before
>   loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without
>   waiting for the document to be ready.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method is the `on()` equivalent for the deprecated method `live()`. Probably your elements get inserted dynamically after the page loading has finished.

You could rewrite your code like following and it should work:

```
$(function() {
    $(".search").on("click", ".remove", function(e) {
        console.log("clicked");
    });
});
```